# how can I show the navigation gps data on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, navigation, gps

I have a GPS device which populates data continuously. I need to show the movement on Google maps. Like for example user is moving from Phoenix to LA. I need show his movement with blue marker on google maps showing his movement along with path traveled.

Is it possible is there an Maps API that does it for me like: I keep pinging the new lat, long to Google maps.  And google maps keep showing the advancing movement on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) which will force you to implement 4 methods. One of those methods is the [onLocationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29) this method, when your location changes will update and do something that you want. I guess you want to update and show your current location.

It is very important that you use [requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) and check this out:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html

Comment: No I don't want to update my current location. I have to show the path traveled by device.

Comment: Do you know any api which helps me do that